# Java Filter a List of Model by a Property and Return the Filter Out List

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, hashmap, set

I have a list of Model class. It contains two field:

```
Class Model {
    String id;
    String type;
}
```

I have a Map structure: 
`Map<String, List<Model>>` each String represents a Name that maps to the `List<Model>`.

Now I want to check if the Name has a distinct `List<Model>`. The List will only consider distinct only if each Model has different type. If there is `Modal A ("abc", "green")`, and next if I see `Modal B ("dbc", "green")`, `Modal C("drrt", "green")`, then `Modal B, Modal C` are not distinctive and I want to store the `Name` and `Modal B, Modal C`, and return`Map<String, List<Modal>>`, which represents the Name that with the list of non-distinctive `List<Model>`;

I thought about building a `Map<String, Set<String>>` structure, `type` as the key, and a `Set<id>` as value, when I iterate the `List<Model>`, I check if the `Map` contains the key I have seen, if it is, add the `id` to`Set`, if it add successfully, means it is non-distinctive, I will add them to the result `Map<String, List<Modal>>`.

But, is there another way, or a more elegant/simple/efficient way to do it, using Java library, or Lambda etc? Please help~~~

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Try to simplify and clearify what you mean. Maybe use something else than code to explain your problem.

Comment: What you're looking for is not difficult at all, but what have you tried so far? Write some code yourself and come back when you have a problem. We are not gonna write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Model>> map = Stream.of(
                new Model("1", "type1"),
                new Model("2", "type2"),
                new Model("3", "type2")
        )
                .collect(groupingBy(m -> "name"));

        Map<String, List<Model>> dupes = map.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(Model::getType))
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(e1 -> e1.getValue().size() > 1)
                        .map(e1 -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), e1.getValue())))
                .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(dupes);

    }

    private static class Model {
        private final String id;
        private final String type;

        public Model(String id, String type) {
            this.id = id;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Model{" +
                    "id='" + id + '\'' +
                    ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Prints {name=[Model{id='2', type='type2'}, Model{id='3', type='type2'}]}